# Switch Case does not respond to initialized function

Tags: javascript

I have recently being practicing an example from a JS book and even after copying the example I was not able to achieve the desired results

Here's the HTML:

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="button" value="Lincoln" id="Lincoln">
    <input type="button" id="Kennedy" value="Kennedy">
    <input type="button" id="Nixon" value="Nixon">
</form>
```

Here's the JS

```
window.onload = initAll;
function initAll() {
    document.getElementById("Lincoln").onclick = saySomething;
    document.getElementById("Kennedy").onclick = saySomething;
    document.getElementById("Nixon").onclick = saySomething;
}

function saySomething() {
    switch(this.id) {
        case "Lincoln":
            alert("Four score and seven years ago...");
            break;
        case "Kennedy":
            alert("Ask not what your country can do for you...");
            break;
        case "Nixon":
            alert("I am not a crook!");
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/kz2y5eak/1/

Comment: [Works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/qun8ah1L/).  Are you using jsfiddle with it's default setting of "wrap in onload"?  If you are, that [doesn't work here](http://jsfiddle.net/qun8ah1L/1/), because you're trying to attach to `onload` after it's already fired.

Comment: Your code seems totally correct.

Comment: I just copied and tested, works just fine

Comment: Thanks all especially james, I had another inline script which had itself firing window.onload();

Comment: Thank you all  I understood my mistake.

Answer (score -1):

I am trying to run code locally but it does not work here I know the code has no issue but then why is it not running locally.

Okay I got it I placed the script external link code in the footer it works fine now.